# AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate sending overlapping shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource calls concurrently

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, avfoundation

I use `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` to stream mp4 videos via a custom protocol.

My code works but seeking through the video is choppy. Oddly enough seeking through the video works much better on iOS 12.

In my project, whenever I get a loading request I start downloading data asynchronously and incrementally provide data to `AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest`. Requests are started and cancelled as needed.

I noticed that sometimes `AVAssetResourceLoader` sends a new request before cancelling the previous request or waiting for the previous request to finish. This behavior doesn't happen on iOS 12 where only one request is active at the same time.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some way in which I can improve seeking performance ?

Example of data ranges that are requested at the start of playback:
A: request range  0 - 2
A: finished loading
B: request range 0 - 39115190
B: cancelled
C: request range 65536 - 39115190
C: cancelled
D: request range 1000 - 39115190
E: request range 393216 - 458752

[Here's a sample project that reproduces the issue](https://github.com/tspop/AVAssetLoaderTest/blob/main/AVAssetLoaderTest/ResourceLoaderDelegate.swift)

Note that downloading data is faked in this project and instead data is incrementally delivered from a background thread